# Writing information to text file

Tags: java, println

We have a problem with writing our ArrayList to a file. 
The file remains empty. We don't find any mistake in our code.
please help us, our deadline is within a few hours...

```
public void rapportAssortiment(String winkelNaam)   throws Exception 
    {
        ArrayList <Artikel> assortiment = db.rapportAssortiment(winkelNaam);
        PrintWriter outputStream = null;
        try
        {
            outputStream = new PrintWriter(new FileOutputStream("RapportAssortiment.txt",true));
            outputStream.println("Rapport van het assortiment van winkel " + winkelNaam);
            outputStream.println("Artikelnummer" + ";" + "Artikelnaam" + ";" + "Prijs" + ";" + "Aantal bonuspunten" + ";" + "Aantal bonuspunten nodig" + ";" + "Minimum aantal stuks" + ";" + "Minimum bedrag" + ";" );
            for(int i = 0; i< assortiment.size(); i++)
            {
                outputStream.println(assortiment.get(i).getArtikelNr() + ";" + assortiment.get(i).getArtikelNaam() + ";" + assortiment.get(i).getPrijs() + ";" + assortiment.get(i).getAantPunten() + ";" + assortiment.get(i).getAantPuntenNodig() + ";" + assortiment.get(i).getMinAantStuks() + ";" + assortiment.get(i).getMinBedrag() );

            }
        }
        catch(Exception exc)
        {
            System.out.println("Rapport trekken mislukt.");
        }
    }
```

Comment: Try closing PrintWriter  with close()

Answer (score 2):

After you're done with writing

```
outputStream.flush();
outputStream.close();
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! We totally forgot about it!